# Bluemix Node.js app not showing new code

Tags: node.js, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

I've built a Node.js app locally that works fine but when I went to test it on Bluemix, it didn't show the app consistently. What I mean is this. I did my cf push. It reported it went up ok. I went to my domain and I saw the original, default BM Node.js 'hello' page. I shift reloaded a few times and *sometimes* I saw my content. Sometimes I saw my HTML and not the CSS. But more often then not I saw the initial BM hello page stuff. It's like there is some serious caching going on the BM side but I do not know how to clear it.

As I said, cf push is reporting everything ok as far as I can see. The File browser in the dashboard is showing old files as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, this was stupid, but I honestly see this as a mistake others can make too so I'll fess up with what I did. My app had "recognition" in the name, and when I created the app I misspelled it as "recognation". So when I did my push it ended up making another app, and I had multiple apps with the same route which apparently confused Bluemix, understandably so I think.

So I guess the take away is - ensure you get the darn app name correct when creating and doing your push. :)

Comment: "ensure you get the darn app name correct when creating and doing your push." Easy mistake, good advice; thanks for posting.

Comment: This is going to sound dumb Xorg, but how?

Comment: Oh never mind, it is the checkmark, which I can't use for two days, because... I don't know.

Comment: Incidentally, having two apps with the same route doesn't confuse Bluemix; that's a supported feature, much like having multiple instances of an app. Requests to the route will be distributed amongst all the apps that are bound to that route.